# Design of Shopping cart, Duplicate subset of productinformation into a line_item keeping quantity count

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How would one get a *subset document* out of the **Product** and make it a **LineItem** product_detail.

What my thought about this design is,

- You create a new LineItem
- inserts a subset document of a Product into LineItem product_detail
- update LineItems values quantity
- decrease quantity of Product with amount "transfered" to LineItem

  ```
  class LineItem  
    field :quantity

    embeds_one :product_detail
  end    

  class ProductDetail
    field :sku
    field :name

    embedded_in :line_item
   end

  class Product       

    field :sku, unique: true
    field :model_no
    field :name
    field :image_url
    field :quantity
  end
  ```

code can be both MongoDB or MongOID